# How may I use ng-click and ng-dblclick in same function in ionic 1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am going to develop an application based on ionic 1 where I need to use `ng-click` and `ng-dblclick` in same event for different purpose. However, `ng-dblclick` is not working here.

Please have a look on my code.

In Html Section:

```
<div ng-click = "clickOnce()" ng-dblclick = "clicktwice()">Enter</div>
```

In Controller I have written:

```
$scope.clickOnce = function () {    
   alert("CLick One");    
}

$scope.clicktwice= function () {    
   alert("CLick two");    
}
```

Application always executive single click. Please tell me, how may I do it.

Comment: check out this http://plnkr.co/edit/hjdVO4ry4fYlXsYMMcJ3?p=preview

Comment: I hope it works for you, good luck  ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

in your controller defined global variable `var count = 1;`

```
$scope.click = function (){
 if(count > 1){
   //your code
   //After its function count = 0;
 } else {
   count = 2;
 }
}
```

or try this too [fuction angular doble click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDblclick)